# What does it mean when we use a variable in C++ like a function with a default value as its parameter?

Tags: c++

I was reading a C++ code line. I encountered a weird code line where a variable was used as a function with a 0 as its parameter!

```
template <class T> class Stack {
    T data[50];
    int nElements;
public:
//This line is where the variable was used like a function!
    Stack() : nElements(0){}
    void push(T elemen);
    T pop();
    int tamanho();
    int isEmpty();
};
```

So what does exactly mean when we have: 
 **the constructor : private variable (0){}**

This code line was very weird for me! 
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't answer my question!

Comment: If you scroll a bit into the accepted answer to "A better way would be for B's constructor to directly call A's constructor in the initializer list..." you can see a discussion and some examples that should answer your question.

Comment: Amir, you'll need to read your C++ text book. This is basic C++.

Comment: @MarkLakata Such comments are best accompanied by [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of `Stack`s constructor, class member `nElements` is initialized with a value of zero upon creation of each `Stack` object.

The value `0` does not have any special meaning here, other than setting the initial number of elements for the `Stack` to zero as soon as it gets created and is empty.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 1):

This is called an 'initializer'. It is saying to initialize the variable with the given value, and the {} indicates the body of the constructor is empty.